# when to use flush after writing to STDOUT?

Tags: ruby

I know what `flush` does. It takes data stored in a buffer and writes it to standard output to empty the buffer. But it is not clear to me when this needs to be done (shouldn't flushing be done automatically by the interpreter). I am reading the book Ruby Programming Language and it gives the example of a socket server:

```
require 'socket'

host, port = ARGV
 begin 
     STDOUT.print "Connnecting..."
     STDOUT.flush
     s = TCPSocket.open(host,port)
     STDOUT.puts "done"

     local, peer = s.addr, s.peeraddr
     STDOUT.print "Connected to #{peer[2]}:#{peer[1]}"
     STDOUT.print "Using local port #{local[1]}"

     begin
         sleep(0.5)
         msg = s.read_nonblock(4096)
         STDOUT.puts msg.chop
     rescue SystemCallError
     end

     loop do
         STDOUT.print '> '
         STDOUT.flush
         local = STDIN.gets
         break if !local

         s.puts(local)
         s.flush

         response = s.readpartial(4096)
         puts(response.chop)
     end
 rescue
     puts $!
 ensure
     s.close if s
 end
```

Why do we invoke flush after writing "Connecting" to STDOUT, but we do not invoke flush after writing "done" to STDOUT? It seems arbitrary here. That is where my confusion is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that "Connecting..." gets printed out before a potentially long-running thing happens.

Once you're connected it's less important to get immediate feedback, and you're flushing after the ">" characters are printed in response to reading data.